# Java Swing loop doesn't work and my JTable doesn't pop up

Tags: java, swing

So I am new to java swing, and I don't understand why my code doesn't loop, shown below:

```java
import javax.swing.*;

public class Lizardo_HW3 {
    JTable t;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String empMax = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many employees you want to input:");
        byte empNumMax = Byte.parseByte(empMax);
        Compute(empNumMax);
    }

    public static void Compute(byte max){
        int empNum[] = new int[max];
        float rateDays[][] = new float[max][2];
        float sal[] = new float[max];
        String[][] tableData = new String[max][3];

        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++){
            String en = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "ID Number:", "Employee Number " + (i + 1), JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            empNum[i] = Integer.parseInt(en);

            String rd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Rate per day:", "Employee Number " + (i + 1), JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            rateDays[i][0] = Float.parseFloat(rd);
            
            String dw = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Days worked:", "Employee Number " + (i + 1), JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            rateDays[i][1] = Float.parseFloat(dw);

            sal[i] = rateDays[i][0] * rateDays[i][1];
            String strSal = String.format("%.02f", sal[i]);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Salary: " + strSal, "Employee Number " + (i + 1), JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            tableData[i][0] = Integer.toString(empNum[i]);
            tableData[i][1] = Float.toString(rateDays[i][0]);
            tableData[i][2] = Float.toString(rateDays[i][1]);
            tableData[i][3] = Float.toString(sal[i]);
        }
        
        
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setTitle("Employee Table");
        String[] columnNames = {"Employee ID", "Rate per Day", "Days Worked", "Salary"};
        JTable t = new JTable(tableData, columnNames);
        t.setBounds(30,40,200,300);

        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(t);
        f.add(sp);
        f.setSize(500,200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This was based on a previous console code my teacher showed which looked like this:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class doodscode {
     static Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         byte empNumMax;

         System.out.println("How many employees you want to input :");
         empNumMax=sc.nextByte();
         Compute(empNumMax);
     }

     public static void Compute(byte max){
         int empnum[]= new int[max];
         float rateDays[][]= new float[max][2];
         float sal[]=new float[max];

         for(int i=0; i<max; i++){
             System.out.println("\t Employee Number :" +(i + 1));
             System.out.println("ID Number : ");
             empnum[i]=sc.nextInt();

             System.out.println("\t Rate Per Days : ");
             rateDays[i][0]=sc.nextFloat();

             System.out.println("\t Days Worked : ");
             rateDays[i][1]=sc.nextFloat();

             sal[i]=rateDays[i][0] * rateDays[i][1];
             System.out.println("\t Salary : " + sal[i]);
         }

         Display(empnum, rateDays, sal, max);
     }

     private static void Display(int[] empnum, float[][] rateDays, float[] sal, byte max){
         System.out.println("EMPLOYEE ID ||  RATE PER DAY  ||  DAYS WORKED ||  SALARY  ");
         for(int j=0; j<max; j++){
             System.out.println(""
             + empnum[j] + "        ||  "
             + rateDays[j][0] + "      ||  "
             + rateDays[j][1] + "      ||  "
             + sal[j]);
         }

     }

}
```

I would like to know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it in order for my code to loop and generate the proper JTable. Much thanks!

Comment: Generally an "int" value is used as an index for looping. Use Integer.parseInt() to get the integer value entered by the user. It loops for me except you get a NullPointerException because you didn't define your array sizes correctly. Array indexes are 0 based. So if you define the array with a size of 3, you can only use indexes 0, 1, 2. You are attempting to use 3 as an index.

Comment: You have an `IndexOutOfBounds` issues on `tableData[i][3] = Float.toString(sal[i]);`, because you've declared the array as only having 3 possible elements, `String[][] tableData = new String[max][3];` should be `String[][] tableData = new String[max][4];`

Comment: @camickr , i tried changing byte to int, and it worked, thanks! I thought I needed to use byte since the console 
code our teacher gave also used the byte data type. I also fixed the incorrect array size, so thank you for that too!